# How do I get (through the JSON API) Drupal to return a Json with a list of taxonomies?

Tags: json, drupal, httprequest, drupal-modules

I want to develop an application on Android that takes the data from my Drupal 8.x.x web page, I take the drupal data through the JSON API.

On my website I have a list of taxonomies that I want to recover, but unlike the data of users, products, etc. when trying to retrieve this list of the form:

GET from `https://www.myweb.com/faqs?_format=json`

I receive this error message:

`"message": "No route found for the specified format json."`

I sense that the API does not generate the JSON file for this list.

Would anyone know how I can retrieve this list of taxonomies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us you "effort"? What did you try so far? I don't want to be rude, but there are tutorials covering this issue, i.e.: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-send-the-json-data-from-a-drupal-8-site-306145e5f5a1

Comment: Thanks, I had read everything I had found about problems with the JSon API of Drupal, and problems with taxonomies and had not found anything. I had tried to get the json of the terms of the taxonomies directly `(/taxonomies/term/{number})`, but with that I only got the title of one, not a list, besides I had the problem of not knowing how many terms of taxonomy there were in every moment

I did not know that you could create a JSON yourself, I had not found any tutorial like the one you put. So THANK YOU!

Comment: P.D.:a so I can not get the data to respond hierarchically (tree structure) the Json, but for me that is a minor problem, I will answer this question when I get it, in case there is another in my same situation. (and I'm sorry for my ignorant question, but I'm a java programmer, not a drupal programmer)